# Only firefox seems to respond?

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze

I just written a long post on a forum and wanted to return back to work and I have this super strange issue that everything accept my browser is frozen.

- My taskbar is completely unresponsive
- I can bring up apps that are currently open, they come forward but they are not responsive, neither can be closed.
- ALT+SHIFT+ESC brings up task manager but is completely unresponsive
- WIN+R brings up the `Run` window and is responsive. But when I run `PowerShell` I get a unresponsive powershell.

Ok, somehow everything is responsive again. Except my Android Studio is behaving weird, it is partially responsive. I closed the app but cannot open it nor other programs on my start dialogue. This took at least 30 minutes since I was trying to find a solution on Internet. What could have caused this and did I somehow by accident froze and unfroze everything except my browser?

Comment: Perhaps you are using too many resources at one time? Check and see if the same problem happens once you restart your computer again. Try and have task manager open first and keep an eye on CPU usage and Memory usage to see if they spike at all. Pay particular attention to remaining unused RAM too.

Comment: @EricF Just running a couple of apps, android studio and firefox being the most heavy. But I have 32GB memory and a brand new haswell processor.

Comment: Have you checked how much stuff is running in the background with msconfig? In general this sounds either like a performance problem (ram, cpu, hard drive speeds) or that something is taking all of your memory / cpu either on purpose or in the form of maleware. Even though you have 32GB of memory, have you checked how much is left over?

Comment: Just trying to help you narrow it down, as you haven't listed many of these details in your question, so it helps anyone reading get a better idea.

Comment: @EricF Thanks, but My CPU is not getting above 10% usage, my memory stays around 25% mostly thanks to firefox. SSD Disk at 0%. I was able to browse perfectly fine at lightning speed, even watched a video that might have gotten me a solution. Of course I cannot go back to the state where everything was unresponsive, but my system is still acting weird. I will restart now, but had to close android studio without being able to save.

Comment: @EricF lol, the dialogue when pressing start is not functioning. I cannot press the power button...

Comment: Have you scanned for a virus / maleware too?

Comment: I remember one time where I had a malfunction of some key (I think Alt or AltGr) which was stuck and made form controls and the taskbar etc. act weird,  so you may check that..